# Wide confidence interval after applying a method

Tags: regression, quantiles

In applied the quantile regression with a B-spline technique in order to calculate the 2.5 and 97.5 quantiles for my several variables/analytes. But I got a very wide confidence interval (gray area) especially at the end of the trend (one year and 19 years) for the estimations. Do you know what the reason is?[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you judge it to be wide?

Comment: My intuition is that, similar to moving average, for the observations on the extreme, you have access to information (i.e, close observations) on only one side, making the interpolation more uncertain.

Comment: In the center of the plot there is data on both the left and right of the data points, giving increased confidence in the model than at the endpoints where there is less data available to characterize that region of the model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your statistics/sample size is heteroscedastic with respect to "age", i.e., you have fewer data points at the end of the intervals. If this is the case, uncertainty about the conditional distribution will grow, specifically about your tail-quintiles.

Comment: You seem erroneously to conflate heteroscedasticity (differences in variance of the conditional distribution) with the intensity of sampling in the regressor.  Indeed the data are heteroscedastic, but if anything that ought (all other things being equal) to result in *smaller* confidence bands at the right side, not larger ones.  Something else is going on here.  One important clue is that the issue applies primarily to the *upper* band, not the lower one (at the right) and primarily to the lower band (at the left).

Comment: Heteroscedasticity implies varying observations for fixed sampling intervals/bin length in most cases, specifically in cross-sectional data. Please do not shoot too early. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are using some kind of special concept of "heteroscedasticity": that would be fine, *but the onus is on you to make your concept clear.*  Otherwise, readers who have a different (and perhaps more standard understanding) may be confused or misled by your post.